# How to extend Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

Tags: orm, laravel, extending-classes

I'm planning to have a function that will store the sql statement on the Cache using the given second parameter on `remember()` as the key and whenever the sql statement changes it will run against the database again and overwrite the stored sql, also the cached result, and if not it will take the default cached result by the `remember()` function.

So I am planning to have something like this on Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

```
/**
 * Execute the query based on the cached query
 *
 * @param  array  $columns
 * @return array|static[]
 */
public function getCacheByQuery($columns = array('*'))
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->cacheMinutes))
    {
        list($key, $minutes) = $this->getCacheInfo();

        // if the stored sql is the same with the new one then get the cached
        // if not, remove the cached query before calling the getCached
        $oldSql = self::flag($key);
        $newSql = $this->toSql().implode(',', $this->bindings);
        if ($newSql!==$oldSql)
        {
            // remove the cache
            \Cache::forget($key);
            // update the stored sql
            self::updateFlag($key, $newSql);
        }

        return $this->getCached($columns);

    }

    return $this->getFresh($columns);
}

public static function updateFlag($flag, $value)
{
    $flags = \Cache::get(t().'databaseFlags', []);
    $flags[$flag] = $value;
    \Cache::put(t().'databaseFlags',  $flags, USER_SESSION_EXPIRATION);
}

public static function flag($flag)
{
    $flags = \Cache::get(t().'databaseFlags', []);
    return @$flags[$flag] ?: false;
}
```

But the thing is, I don't want to put this directly on Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder since it is just my need for the current application I am working. I'm trying to extend Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder, but the problem is it does not detect the my extension class.

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getCachedByQuery()
```

My Extension Class

```
<?php namespace Lukaserat\Traits;

class QueryBuilder extends \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder  {

    /**
     * Execute the query based on the caced query
     *
     * @param  array  $columns
     * @return array|static[]
     */
    public function getCachedByQuery($columns = array('*'))
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->cacheMinutes))
        {
            list($key, $minutes) = $this->getCacheInfo();

            // if the stored sql is the same with the new one then get the cached
            // if not, remove the cached query before calling the getCached
            $oldSql = self::flag($key);
            $newSql = $this->toSql().implode(',', $this->bindings);
            if ($newSql!==$oldSql)
            {
                // remove the cache
                \Cache::forget($key);
                // update the stored sql
                self::updateFlag($key, $newSql);
            }

            return $this->getCached($columns);

        }

        return $this->getFresh($columns);
    }

    public static function updateFlag($flag, $value)
    {
        $flags = \Cache::get(t().'databaseFlags', []);
        $flags[$flag] = $value;
        \Cache::put(t().'databaseFlags',  $flags, USER_SESSION_EXPIRATION);
    }

    public static function flag($flag)
    {
        $flags = \Cache::get(t().'databaseFlags', []);
        return @$flags[$flag] ?: false;
    }


}
```

Implementing on..

```
<?php
use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;
use Lukaserat\Traits\DataTable;
use Lukaserat\Traits\QueryBuilder as QueryBuilder;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag as MessageBag;

class ArdentBase extends Ardent implements InterfaceArdentBase{
    use DataTable;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Guys,

I was able to extend it by putting a copy of the `newBaseQueryBuilder()` on the `ArdentBase` class. But I'm not getting a Collection object as I expected. I'm getting.. `LaravelBook\Ardent\Builder` object

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct that I overwrite the `get()` method on the Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder by renaming the function I made in my extension class from `getCachedByQuery` to `get` since I just extending the routine of the `get`.

I changed

```
public function getCachedByQuery($columns = array('*'))
```

to

```
public function get()
```

on my `Lukaserat\Traits\QueryBuilder`

and it is now working as I expected..